# Powershell - proper way to execute SQL query with multiple select statements and result tables

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, resultset

I'm trying to execute an SQL query with few select statements, that returns multiple tables as a result. The problem is that I can't find a way to read and use the tables separately.

**Expected results:**

[image]

**Actual results:** (it is printed row by row)

[image]

**Purpose**: I've made a script that creates an empty excel file with multiple sheets and each of the sheets will be used to contain each resultset of the query. 
The only thing left is to put the needed text into the sheets. Here is my code for that part only:

```
$ConnectionString = "Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;User Id=...;Password=..."
$DBServerName = $ConnectionString.split('=')[1].split(';')[0]
$DBName = $ConnectionString.split('=')[2].split(';')[0]
$DBUser = $ConnectionString.split('=')[3].split(';')[0]
$DBPassword = $ConnectionString.split('=')[4].split(';')[0]

$CurrentFilePath = "C:\SQLqueryWithManyResultsets.sql"

$query = Get-Content -literalPath $CurrentFilePath | Out-String #getting the query string from file

$resultTables = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $DBServerName -Database $DBName -DisableVariables -Password $DBPassword -Username $DBUser -ErrorAction Stop

foreach ($result in $resultTables) {
    $result | Format-Table  #where the magic happens
}
```

I've made a lot of research, but I cannot find a proper way to store and read the tables the way i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear-Host;
$objConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$objConnection.ConnectionString = "...";


$ObjCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$ObjCmd.CommandText = "...";
$ObjCmd.Connection = $objConnection;
$ObjCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

$objAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$objAdapter.SelectCommand = $ObjCmd;
$objDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;

$objAdapter.Fill($objDataSet) | Out-Null;

for ($i=0; $i -lt $objDataSet.Tables.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host ($objDataSet.Tables[$i] | Format-Table | Out-String);
}


$query = $null;

$objDataSet = $null;

$objConnection.Close();
$objConnection = $null;
```